# I have removed a route from web.php and this route still working in laravel 5

Tags: laravel, routes

I am working in laravel 5 an existing project downloaded from cpanel. I want to make some changes but my changes do not have any affect. I, at the end remove the route but route still working. There is no any extra route file binding in routeServiceProvider not required or included in web.php. I am wondering how it could be happened?
I have tried:

```
php aritsan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
```

can somebody please tell me what could be the issue ?

Comment: i also restarted the server.

Comment: try this php artisan  route:clear

Answer (score 1):

please run the following:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

After running this command, your cached routes file will be loaded on every request.

Comment: What is the point of posting the same answer as me? :D

Comment: @keneferinho95 technically this is `route:cache` not `route:clear`

Comment: Alrighty, my bad...

Comment: while in development there is no reason to cache your routes, just clear them with `route:clear`, otherwise you will have to keep recaching them every time you make a change

Answer (score 0):

Please, run the following command:

```
php artisan route:clear
```

Comment: it's route:cache, or cache:clear

Comment: @Jack `route:clear` clears the route cache so not wrong and `cache:clear` has nothing to do with the route or config cache, that is your actual cache store you are telling people to flush (which doesn't help at all) ... the OP doesn't need their routes cached in the first place

Comment: @lagbox you are correct, I was wrong.